# Using Azure AsyncBlobClient for upload

Tags: java, azure, sdk, azure-blob-storage

I want to use the Azure AsyncBlobClient to upload files to a storage account.

My code looks like this:

```
BlobAsyncClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
    .credential(cred)
    .containerName(sf_blob_container)
    .blobName(fname)
    .buildAsyncClient();

blobClient
    .uploadFromFile(fname, true)
    .doOnSuccess(success -> { System.out.println(String.format("File: %s: Upload successful.",fname)); })
    .doOnError(error -> { System.out.println(String.format("File: %s: Upload Error!.",fname)); })
    .subscribe(completion -> System.out.println("Upload from file succeeded");
```

It works as expected, but the last upload gets terminated because the process comes to an end.

How can I ensure, that the process waits for all async uploads to finish?

Best regards
Stefan

Comment: Could you update the details of your error?

Comment: @PamelaPeng: There is no error. The Java process exits cleanly, but the blob isn't uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you want blocking call, replace subscribe with then (returns Mono) and then block on it like below.

```
BlobAsyncClient blobClient = new BlobClientBuilder()
    .credential(cred)
    .containerName(sf_blob_container)
    .blobName(fname)
    .buildAsyncClient();

blobClient
    .uploadFromFile(fname, true)
    .doOnSuccess(success -> { System.out.println(String.format("File: %s: Upload successful.",fname)); })
    .doOnError(error -> { System.out.println(String.format("File: %s: Upload Error!.",fname)); })
    .then()
    .block();
```